# Deutsches Äquivalent zu „put your neck/ ass on the line“

Tags: english-to-german, idiom, phrase-request

Die englische Redewendung

> - put your neck on the line *(en-GB)*
> - put your ass on the line *(en-US)*

wird auf der Seite von [The Free Dictionary by Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+your+ass+on+the+line) wie folgt erklärt:

> To personally assume or expose oneself to some risk, danger, or responsibility; to imperil oneself or put oneself in harm's way.
>
> > Look, I'm putting my neck on the line for you here. I could get fired if they find out what we're up to!
>
> > You have to take some risks to be successful in business and in life, but don't put your neck on the line for no good reason.

Gibt es eine äquivalente Redewendung auf Deutsch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Thorsten focused more on the "put your ass on the line" variant in his answer.

"put your neck on the line" is mostly translated as

> seinen Kopf/Hals hinhalten (für etwas)
>
> seinen Kopf/Hals riskieren (für etwas)
>
> Kopf und Kragen riskieren

or - depending on context - figuratively

> sein Leben (für etwas) aufs Spiel setzen

Answer (score 2):

The "on the line" part is in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_line) (def. 2). "Neck" and "ass" are commonly used  representatives for one's personal survival, or one's job or other figurative extension. So the above expressions just combine the two, and I don't think they're a idioms themselves since the the two parts can be translated independently. As pointed out in the other answers, *Kopf* can be used as a translation for "neck" in this context, though *Hals* is a more literal translation. I'm not convinced *Arsch* isn't too literal a translation of "ass"; English has so many figurative meanings for the word it's hard for me to tell. As also pointed out in the other answers, *in die Schusslinie*, in English "in the line of fire", means a spot where enemy soldiers can shoot at you. I don't know the origin of "on the line", but it might be related to "the front line", a military term for the foremost soldiers in a battle, in which case "on the line" and "in the firing line" would be nearly equivalent.

PS. According to [this answer from the English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/275540), "on the line" was a originally a gambling term. So apparently "in the firing line" is not as closely related as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Das deutsche Äquivalent hierfür ist -wie Dir jedes gute Onlinewörterbuch sagt-

> Sich selbst in die Schusslinie begeben

Oder wenn Du beim Pejorativ bleiben willst:

> seinen Arsch riskieren

Beide Beispiele findet man direkt so bei [dict](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Put%20your%20ass%20in%20the%20line).

Fürs nächste Mal: Üblicherweise werden hier Fragen, die direkt mit einem Wörterbuch beantwortet werden können direkt und ohne Antwort geschlossen...

Comment: Es ist weder auf pons.de und noch auf linguee.de duckduckgo hat es auch nicht gefunden das sollte reichen um eine Frage hier zu stellen!!

Comment: Dann hattest Du einfach Pech. Die erste Quelle, die ich gecheckt habe, hatte es gleich. Solche Recherchen erwähnt man am besten gleich in der Frage, dann riskiert man auch nicht, dass die Frage geschlossen wird...